# Ruby on Rails continuously running function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I'm building an application on RoR that requires a function that is continuously running in the background. The function will poll the database to find records that have a date/time associated with them. Based on the value of the date-time, it will trigger some other function.

What RoR feature can I use to achieve this?

As an alternate, I could have an action method that is called based on some dynamically set time value (instead of polling the database for date-time). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might need a task scheduler. Ruby on Rails doesn't itself provide a feature to run background tasks.

You might want to check out `clockwork` gem https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork for this kind of functionality.